# IBM Watson - How to get login from user with Regex

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm working with IBM Watson API's a few months ago.

I want to know more about Regex inside the Conversation Service. And how to get the login from the user, if they type some like:

- My login is sayuri.mizuguchi!
- My login? ooh, is sayuri.mizuguchi

The default is always `firstname.lastname`.

I want use `input.text.find` to get the login, and with one context variable I'll save the login, like:

```
{
  "context": {
    "loginUser": <? input.text ?>
  },
```

Simon did the same but with other data, 11 numbers and works amazingly.

In this case I'll use just `input.text` because my `input.text.find` inside the node with IF condition will extract my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution with regex, @revo help with one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940353/regex-to-extract-login-username).

Try this inside the if condition:

```
input.text.find('\w+\.\w')
```

And only if user types login, the conversation will flow.