# Regex to extract login username

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Currently, I had one Web chat project, I use socket.io to send and receive messages real time.
I need to get the login if user types.

I try to use regex but I'm a beginner within and the format can be multiples like:

- My login is sayuri.mizuguchi
- My login? So, sayuri.mizuguchi Okay?

The format from login is always firstname.lastname

In this case, all messages stay inside a parameter and this data is saved inside one variable but I really try use multiples regex for test and anything works.
Someone can help me, please?

Example:

```
console.log(data.usertyped); // My login is sayuri.mizuguchi
```

I need use like *condition*, like: `input.text.find('\d{11}')` that get 11 numbers within a condition even if the user types "My number is 11122233344" and I need the same to get login.

Thanks advance.

Comment: regex is used to test the value against a pattern to ensure data isn't incorrectly set in a database - surely you just want to check user credentials from the db?

Comment: In this case it's just a simple conversation that I need to get the user login, there is no db, it's just to check if they typed correctly

Comment: So you need a regex like [**`^\w+\.\w+$`**](https://regex101.com/r/qf4HJI/1)?

Comment: With your regex I delete the caracther ^ and $ and works perfectly. Independ if user typed in the final, or start typed the login, the regex extract the data. Can you please answer my question here and I'll mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to match a string in format of `----.----` where each `-` denotes a word character (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`) you have to work with `\w` meta-character which means all of it:

```
^\w+\.\w+$
```

Using `^` and `$` anchors make sure regex should start to match from beginning of an input string to its end respectfully otherwise it should fail. Like in following cases:

1. `@firstname.lastname`
2. `mohammad.hoss*ein`

To add more characters into consideration you need to use character classes:

```
^[\w@-]+\.[\w@-]+$
```

Also you should know the least needed characters that `^\w+\.\w+$` expects is a word character in both sides of the period:

```
a.b
```